# capybara/selenium form_tag - element not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, selenium, capybara

I have the following form:

```
<div class="row search-area" id="test">
  <%= form_tag search_index_path, method: :get do %>
  <div class="small-12 medium-1 large-1 columns search-field">
    <%= label_tag "From", nil, class: "right inline" %>
  </div>
  <div class="small-12 medium-2 large-2 columns search-field">
    <%= text_field_tag(:start_date, params[:start_date], :value => "yyyy-mm-dd", :class => "datepicker") %>
  </div>
  <div class="small-12 medium-1 large-1 columns search-field">
    <%= label_tag "To", nil, class: "right inline" %>
  </div>
  <div class="small-12 medium-2 large-2 columns search-field">
    <%= text_field_tag(:end_date, params[:end_date], :value => "yyyy-mm-dd", :class => "datepicker") %>
  </div>
  <div class="small-12 medium-1 large-1 columns search-field">
    <%= label_tag "Guests", nil, class: "right inline" %>
  </div>
  <div class="small-12 medium-2 large-2 columns search-field">
    <%= number_field(:number_of_guests, params[:number_of_guests], in: 1.0..20.0, step: 1.0) %>
  </div>
  <div class="small-12 medium-3 large-3 columns">
    <%= submit_tag "Search", name: nil, :class => "button" %>
  </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

I'm trying to write some feature specs to make sure that the search works as expected. I'm pretty new to this but after reading a few tutorials I ended up with the following test:

```
describe "search form works" do
  context "search", :driver => :selenium do
    it "searches bookings for hosts" do
      visit root_url
      fill_in 'start_date', with: "2015-06-01"
      fill_in 'end_date', with: "2015-06-07"
      select "1", :from => 'number_of_guests'
      click_button 'Search'

      expect(page).to have_content 'Mr Host 5'
    end
  end
end
```

The problem is that when I run my tests I get the following error:

```
Failures:

  1) search form works search searches bookings for hosts
     Failure/Error: fill_in 'start_date', with: "2015-06-01"
     Capybara::ElementNotFound:
       Unable to find field "start_date"
     # ./spec/features/search_spec.rb:7:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Is the problem that I'm using `form_tag` (all the examples and tutorials I've read/watched have used 'form_tag')?

Answer (score 0):

Taking a guess from the class 'datepicker' you have on each of your date fields - Are these fields being converted into some sort of javascript driven date picking widget?  If so and you look at the actual html on the page once the fields have been converted you will most likely see that the input fields with the names 'start_date' and 'end_date' are actually hidden.  Capybara by default doesn't find fields that aren't visible on the page because a user wouldnt be able to interact with them.  There are two solutions to this - the first would be to tell Capybara to find hidden elements too

```
fill_in 'start_date', visible: false, with: "2015-06-01"
```

This will work in some drivers but is pretty hacky since it's no longer replicating a users behavior.  The second solution is to actually replicating the users behavior by calling #click on the elements on the page the user would actually have to click on to enter the date.